# Replacing Values in a String

Tags: javascript, string, function, loops, methods

Forgive me if this question has already been asked; I've searched the site for this question and haven't stumbled upon it yet.

I'm creating a word-guessing game, and I'm having trouble with the last of my functions. The function arguments are a user-inputted character ("character"), a randomly generated word ("word"), and a scrambled version of that word ("scrmbldword"). As an example, the word could be "chilly", and the scrambled version would have a corresponding number of underscores "______". The role of this function is to take the user input, scan the "word" for that letter, and if it finds that letter in the word, to replace an underscore of the "scrmbldword" with the corresponding letter.

For instance, the word would be "chilly", and the user input would be the character "l"; I need the scrmbldword to become "___ll_".

```
function unscrambledWord(character, scrmbldword, word) {
  for (k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {
    if (character == word[k]) {
      var tempLetter = word[k];
      console.log(tempLetter)
      tempWord = scrmbldword.replace(scrmbldword[k], character);
      console.log(tempWord);
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for all the answers, but when I copy and paste them into my code, they are not working. I'm trying to understand the code behind your various answers so I can edit them myself, but for the most part I don't get it. Perhaps it would help you all if I gave more context, so here's my file entirely...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Word Guess Game</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div>
    <p id="directions-text">Type any letter to start playing</p>
    <p id="userchoice-text"></p>
    <p id="userguesslist-text"></p>
    <p id="unscrambledword-text"></p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var userGuesses = [];
    var unknownWord = "";

function wordGenerator() {
  var computerChoices = ["lowly", "start", "chilly", "bun", "bead", "friend", "return", "view", "cloth", "frogs", "celery", "basin", "stand", "special", "broad", "abaft", "plead", "quartz", "mark", "tempt", "shop", "stone", "scorch", "taboo", "hoax", "spiffy", "insure"];
  var cpuWord = computerChoices[Math.floor(Math.random() * computerChoices.length)];
  console.log(cpuWord);
  return cpuWord;
};
var computerWord = wordGenerator();

function scrambledWord(string) {
  var knownWord = ""
  if (string.length == 3) {
    knownWord = "___"
  } else if (string.length == 4) {
    knownWord = "____"
  } else if (string.length == 5) {
    knownWord = "_____"
  } else if (string.length == 6) {
    knownWord = "______"
  } else if (string.length == 7) {
    knownWord = "_______"
  }
  return knownWord;
}
var unknownWord = scrambledWord(computerWord);

var directionsText = document.getElementById("directions-text");
var userChoiceText = document.getElementById("userchoice-text");
var userGuessList = document.getElementById("userguesslist-text");
var unscrambledWordText = document.getElementById("unscrambledword-text");

document.onkeyup = function (event) {

  var userGuess = event.key;

  if ((userGuess === "a") || (userGuess === "b") || (userGuess === "c") || (userGuess === "d") || (userGuess === "e") || (userGuess === "f") || (userGuess === "g") || (userGuess === "h") || (userGuess === "i") || (userGuess === "j") || (userGuess === "k") || (userGuess === "l") || (userGuess === "m") || (userGuess === "n") || (userGuess === "o") || (userGuess === "p") || (userGuess === "q") || (userGuess === "r") || (userGuess === "s") || (userGuess === "t") || (userGuess === "u") || (userGuess === "v") || (userGuess === "w") || (userGuess === "x") || (userGuess === "y") || (userGuess === "z")) {
    userGuesses.push(userGuess);
    directionsText.textContent = "";

    userChoiceText.textContent = "You chose: " + userGuess;
    userGuessList.textContent = "You have guessed: " + userGuesses;
    unscrambledWordText.textContent = "The word is: " + unknownWord;
    wordChecker(userGuess)
  } else {
    alert("You did not enter an alphabetical character.")
  }
};

function wordChecker(input) {
  if (computerWord.includes(input)) {
    alert("You guessed a correct character")
    unscrambledWord(input, unknownWord, computerWord)
  } else {
    alert("You guessed an incorrect character")
  }
}

function unscrambledWord(character, scrmbldword, word) {
  for (k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {
    if (character == word[k]) {
      var tempLetter = word[k];
      console.log(tempLetter)
      tempWord = scrmbldword.replace(scrmbldword[k], character);
      console.log(tempWord);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding, you can try this

```js
function unscrambledWord(character, word, scrmbldword = "_".repeat(word.length)) {
 return [...scrmbldword].map((d, i) => d == '_' && word[i] == character ? character : d).join('')
}

console.log(unscrambledWord('l', 'chilly'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [Nitish Narang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3048429/nitish-narang) is really a nice answer, but if you really want to use your existing function, you can try to define and use a `replaceAt` function, like this :

```js
function unscrambledWord(character, scrmbldword, word) {
  for (k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {
    if (character == word[k]) {
      var tempLetter = word[k];
      console.log(tempLetter)
      tempWord = scrmbldword.replaceAt(k, character);
      console.log(tempWord);
    }
  }
}

String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, replacement) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + replacement+ this.substr(index + replacement.length);
}

unscrambledWord("l", "______", "chilly")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace method with a RegExp that has the global flag, which tells us to replace all instances of that RegExp.

```
RegExp(`[^${character}]`, "g")
```

We're making a regex that matches any character except the provided character.

```
function unscrambledWord(character, word) {
    const notCharacter = RegExp(`[^${character}]`, "g")
    return word.replace(notCharacter, "_")
}
```